# How to read records in JSON format from Kafka using Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to use [structured streaming approach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) using Spark-Streaming based on DataFrame/Dataset API to load a stream of data from Kafka.

I use:

- Spark 2.10
- Kafka 0.10
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10

Spark Kafka DataSource has defined underlying schema:

```
|key|value|topic|partition|offset|timestamp|timestampType|
```

My data come in json format and they are stored in the *value* column. I am looking for a way how to extract underlying schema from value column and update received dataframe to columns stored in *value*? I tried the approach below but it does not work:

```
 val columns = Array("column1", "column2") // column names
 val rawKafkaDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe",topic)
  .load()
  val columnsToSelect = columns.map( x => new Column("value." + x))
  val kafkaDF = rawKafkaDF.select(columnsToSelect:_*)

  // some analytics using stream dataframe kafkaDF

  val query = kafkaDF.writeStream.format("console").start()
  query.awaitTermination()
```

Here I am getting Exception `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from value#337;` because in time of creation of the stream, values inside are not known...

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the Spark perspective `value` is just a  byte sequence. It has no knowledge about the serialization format or content. To be able to extract the filed you have to parse it first.

If data is serialized as a JSON string you have two options. You can `cast` `value` to `StringType` and use `from_json` and provide a schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json

val schema: StructType = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("column1", ???),
  StructField("column2", ???)
))

rawKafkaDF.select(from_json($"value".cast(StringType), schema))
```

or `cast` to `StringType`, extract fields by path using `get_json_object`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.get_json_object

val columns: Seq[String] = ???

val exprs = columns.map(c => get_json_object($"value", s"$$.$c"))

rawKafkaDF.select(exprs: _*)
```

and `cast` later to the desired types.

Comment: FWIW, i find both alternatives clunky:

+ the schema alternative requires schema specification using Spark native code. So if we are shipping a complicated schema, code has to parse a schema file (xsd etc) and build this object.  


+ get_json_object alternative forces individually popping out paths/fields. I'm not sure whats the performance penalty of this.  

I'd have prefered if Apache Spark shipped with a easier way to cleanly accept a schema file and generate Spark/Catalyst schema object.

Comment: another way to get schema for messages (its yet another clunky way):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361177/spark-structured-streaming-kafka-convert-json-without-schema-infer-schema

Comment: i am having hard time to do it in python. can anyone suggest same.