# How to extract information from a nested XML_String in Spark-Structured-Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark-structured application connected to ActiveMQ. The application receives messages from a topic. These messages are in the form of a StringXML. I want to extract information from this nested-XML. How can I do this?

I referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004610/how-to-read-streaming-data-in-xml-format-from-kafka), but was not able to implement something similar in Scala.

XML Format:

```
<CofiResults>
  <ExecutionTime>20201103153839</ExecutionTime>
  <FilterClass>S </FilterClass>
  <InputData format="something" id="someID"><ns2:FrdReq xmlns:ns2="http://someone.com">
    <HeaderSegment xmlns="https://somelink.com">
        <Version>6</Version>
        <SequenceNb>1</SequenceNb>
    </HeaderSegment>
.
.
.
```

My Code:

```
val df = spark.readStream
            .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
            .option("brokerUrl", brokerUrl_)
            .option("topic", topicName_)
            .option("persistence", "memory")
            .option("cleanSession", "true")
            .option("username", username_)
            .option("password", password_)
            .load()

val payload_ = df.select('payload cast "string") // This payload IS the XMLString
```

Now I need to extract `ExecutionTime`, `Version`, and other fields from the above XML.

Comment: That uses `import xml.etree.ElementTree` I am fairly new to Scala... and have no Idea how I can do this

Comment: how about using xpath in spark sql?https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#xpath

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use it in a UDF? Thanks

Comment: if you want to use xpath then you don't need udf, just call `spark.sql("select xpath(payload, <xpathquery>)")` with the appropriate xpath query

Comment: here the variable `payload` is a dataframe right? and xpath requires a String

Comment: sorry, I meant `spark.sql("select xpath(payload, <xpathquery>) from dataframe")`. payload is the xml string column

Comment: Thanks a lot... after converting the dataframe to tempTable and then running the sql command it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SQL built-in](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#xpath) functions `xpath` and the like to extract data from a nested XML structure.

Given a nested XML like (for simplicity, I have omitted any tag parameters)

```
<CofiResults>
  <ExecutionTime>20201103153839</ExecutionTime>
  <FilterClass>S</FilterClass>
  <InputData>
    <ns2>
      <HeaderSegment>
        <Version>6</Version>
        <SequenceNb>1</SequenceNb>
      </HeaderSegment>
    </ns2>
  </InputData>
</CofiResults>
```

you can then just use those SQL functions (without `createOrReplaceTempView`) in your `selectExpr` statment as below:

```scala
  .selectExpr("CAST(payload AS STRING) as payload")
  .selectExpr(
    "xpath(payload, '/CofiResults/ExecutionTime/text()') as ExecutionTimeAsArryString",
    "xpath_long(payload, '/CofiResults/ExecutionTime/text()') as ExecutionTimeAsLong",
    "xpath_string(payload, '/CofiResults/ExecutionTime/text()') as ExecutionTimeAsString",
    "xpath_int(payload, '/CofiResults/InputData/ns2/HeaderSegment/Version/text()') as VersionAsInt")
```

Remember that the `xpath` function will return an *Array* of Strings whereas you may find it more convenient to extract the value as String or even Long. Applying the code above in Spark 3.0.1 with a console sink stream will result in:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+
|ExecutionTimeAsArryString|ExecutionTimeAsLong|ExecutionTimeAsString|VersionAsInt|
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+
|[20201103153839]         |20201103153839     |20201103153839       |6           |
+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+
```