# Spark structured streaming kafka convert JSON without schema (infer schema)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, schema, spark-structured-streaming

I read Spark Structured Streaming doesn't support schema inference for reading Kafka messages as JSON. Is there a way  to retrieve schema  the same as Spark Streaming does:

```
val dataFrame = spark.read.json(rdd.map(_.value()))
dataFrame.printschema
```

Comment: Could you explain the context? It sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I"m trying to consume from Kafka to our columnar DB.  We don't have schema on our topic and I would like to query the topic with optional columns. Is it possible to build schema with optional columns, structured streaming?

Comment: What do you mean by optional? Not existing int records? Just define a static schema with nullable fields.

Answer (score 13):

Here is one possible way to do this:

1. Before you start streaming, get a small batch of the data from Kafka
2. Infer the schema from the small batch
3. Start streaming the data using the extracted schema.

The pseudo-code below illustrates this approach.

Step 1:

Extract a small (two records) batch from Kafka,

```
val smallBatch = spark.read.format("kafka")
                           .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "node:9092")
                           .option("subscribe", "topicName")
                           .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                           .option("endingOffsets", """{"topicName":{"0":2}}""")
                           .load()
                           .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as STRING").as[String].toDF()
```

Step 2:
Write the small batch to a file:

```
smallBatch.write.mode("overwrite").format("text").save("/batch")
```

This command writes the small batch into hdfs directory /batch. The name of the file that it creates is part-xyz*. So you first need to rename the file using hadoop FileSystem commands (see org.apache.hadoop.fs._ and org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration, here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41990859) and then read the file as json:

```
val smallBatchSchema = spark.read.json("/batch/batchName.txt").schema
```

Here, batchName.txt is the new name of the file and smallBatchSchema contains the schema inferred from the small batch.

Finally, you can stream the data as follows (Step 3):

```
val inputDf = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
                             .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "node:9092")
                             .option("subscribe", "topicName")
                             .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                             .load()

val dataDf = inputDf.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json")
                    .select( from_json($"json", schema=smallBatchSchema).as("data"))
                    .select("data.*")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any other way without writing to a file?

Answer (score 9):

It *is* possible using this construct:

```
myStream = spark.readStream.schema(spark.read.json("my_sample_json_file_as_schema.json").schema).json("my_json_file")..
```

How can this be? Well, as the spark.read.json("..").schema returns exactly a wanted inferred schema, you can use this returned schema as an argument for the mandatory schema parameter of spark.readStream

What I did was to specify a one-liner sample-json as input for inferring the schema stuff so it does not unnecessary take up memory. In case your data changes, simply update your sample-json.

Took me a while to figure out (constructing StructTypes and StructFields by hand was pain in the ..), therefore I'll be happy for all upvotes :-)

Comment: Is there any other way without writing to a file?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. Spark Streaming supports limited schema inference in development with `spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference` set to `true`:

> By default, Structured Streaming from file based sources requires you to specify the schema, rather than rely on Spark to infer it automatically. This restriction ensures a consistent schema will be used for the streaming query, even in the case of failures. For ad-hoc use cases, you can reenable schema inference by setting spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference to true.

but it cannot be used to extract JSON from Kafka messages and `DataFrameReader.json` doesn't support streaming `Datasets` as arguments.

You have to provide schema manually [How to read records in JSON format from Kafka using Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43297973/8371915)

Comment: Today we consume through spark streaming and we don"t  have a schema. I'm using the DateFrame.schema  Is it possible to retrieve the schema.      
val df = stream.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as json") retrieve  it  from df ?

Comment: Thx, Any ideas for consuming Kafka with Spark structured streaming and convert JSON without schema???

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to convert JSON to a DataFrame without *having to manually type* the schema, if that is what you meant to ask.

Recently I ran into a situation where I was receiving massively long nested JSON packets via Kafka, and manually typing the schema would have been both cumbersome and error-prone.

With a small sample of the data and some trickery you can provide the schema to Spark2+ as follows:

```
val jsonstr = """ copy paste a representative sample of data here"""
val jsondf = spark.read.json(Seq(jsonstr).toDS) //jsondf.schema has the nested json structure we need

val event = spark.readStream.format..option...load() //configure your source

val eventWithSchema = event.select($"value" cast "string" as "json").select(from_json($"json", jsondf.schema) as "data").select("data.*")
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this val as you would with Direct Streaming. Create temp view, run SQL queries, whatever..

Answer (score 2):

Taking [Arnon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1488754/arnon-rodman) solution to the next step (since it's deprecated in spark's newer versions, and would require iterating the whole dataframe just for a type casting)

```
spark.read.json(df.as[String])
```

Anyways, as for now, it's still experimental.

Comment: What exactly is deprecated?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L404