# Spark Json Iteration

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Input Json Data looks as below.

```
{
    "CarBrands": [
        {
            "model": "audi",
            "make": " (YEAR == \"2009\" AND CONDITION in  (\"Y\")  AND RESALE in  (\"2015\")) ",
            "service": {
                "first": null,
                "second": [],
                "third": []
            },
            "dealerspot": [
                {
                    "dealername": [
                        "\"first\"",
                        "\"abc\""
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dealerlat": [
                        "\"45.00\"",
                        "\"38.00\""
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "ok",
            "plate": true
        },
        {
            "model": "bmw",
            "make": " (YEAR == \"2010\" AND CONDITION OR  (\"N\")  AND RESALE in  (\"2016\")) ",
            "service": {
                "first": null,
                "second": [],
                "third": []
            },
            "dealerspot": [
                {
                    "dealername": [
                        "\"sports\"",
                        "\"abc\""
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dealerlat": [
                        "\"45.00\"",
                        "\"38.00\""
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "ok",
            "plate": true
        },
        {
            "model": "toy",
            "make": " (YEAR == \"2013\" AND CONDITION in  (\"Y\")  AND RESALE in  (\"2018\")) ",
            "service": {
                "first": null,
                "second": [],
                "third": []
            },
            "dealerspot": [
                {
                    "dealername": [
                        "\"nelson\"",
                        "\"abc\""
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "dealerlat": [
                        "\"45.00\"",
                        "\"38.00\""
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "type": "ok",
            "plate": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to process this file in spark using scala and expected output in a dataframe

```
+----- -+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+
| model | year  | condition | cond_operator | resale | resale_operator |dealername  |
+-------+-------+-----------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+
|audi   | 2009  |  Y        |    in         |  2015  | in              | first      |
|bmw    | 2010  |  N        |    OR         |  2016  | in              | sports     |
|toy    | 2013  |  Y        |    in         |  2018  | in              | nelson     |
+------ +-------+-----------+---------------+--------+-----------------+------------+
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800906/array-of-json-to-dataframe-in-spark-received-by-kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please find the solution**

```
package stackoverflow

import utils.Context
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

object JsonSample extends App with Context {

  import sparkSession.implicits._
  val tagsDF = sparkSession.read
    .option("multiLine", true)
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .json("src/main/resources/carbrands.json");
  val df = tagsDF.select(explode($"CarBrands") as "car_brands")

df.printSchema()

  val dfd = df.withColumn("_tmp", split($"car_brands.make", "\"")).select(
    $"car_brands.model".as("model"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(1).as("year"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(2).as("col3"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(3).as("condition"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(4).as("col5"),
    $"_tmp".getItem(5).as("resale"),
    $"car_brands.dealerspot.dealername"(0)(0).as("dealer")
  ).withColumn("_tmp2",split($"col3", " ")).select(
    $"model",
    $"year",
    $"condition",
    $"_tmp2".getItem(3).as("cond_operator"),
    $"resale",
    $"col5",
    $"dealer")
  .withColumn("_tmp1",split($"col5", " ")).select(
    $"model",
    $"year",
    $"condition",
    $"cond_operator",
    $"resale",

    $"_tmp1".getItem(4).as("resale_operator"),
    $"dealer"
  )
  dfd.show()

}
```

**Output**

```
 +-----+----+---------+-------------+------+---------------+--------+
|model|year|condition|cond_operator|resale|resale_operator|  dealer|
+-----+----+---------+-------------+------+---------------+--------+
| audi|2009|        Y|           in|  2015|             in| "first"|
|  bmw|2010|        N|           OR|  2016|             in|"sports"|
|  toy|2013|        Y|           in|  2018|             in|"nelson"|
+-----+----+---------+-------------+------+---------------+--------+
```