# Infer safe schema from a structured streaming dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, schema, spark-structured-streaming

I wanted to infer a safe schema from a JSON data coming from Kafka.

```py
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "input").option("auto.offset.reset", "latest").load()
jsonDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) jsonData")
```

There are a couple of solutions on stackoverflow:

1. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361177/spark-structured-streaming-kafka-convert-json-without-schema-infer-schema) says to save a small batch into a file, infer the schema and then use that schema for the streaming dataframe. Although the question is a year old.
2. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069282/how-to-query-json-data-column-using-spark-dataframes) uses `schema_of_json` and `lit` ,although I'm not able to get it to work with streaming DFs.

I know inferring of schema can be dangerous, but the spark application I'm developing has multiple sources with varied schemas(multiple columns). Is there a way I can create a schema based on the columns in the json data and force cast them to `String` to prevent data loss.

Comment: If `schema_of_json` is not working, you could create an udf with [genson](https://github.com/wolverdude/GenSON/).

Comment: @cronoik can you give an example of this. The dataframe I'm working with is a streaming dataframe.

Comment: Sure, but please add some an example of json messages to your question before.