# How can I use spark-sql to read and process a JSON event from kafka?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Elaborated: looking to implement scala code using structured spark streaming, DataFrame to read a JSON event from Kafka, and use spark-sql to manipulate data/columns and write it to hive?

*Using scala 2.11/spark 2.2*

I understand creating the connection is straight forward:

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

How do I handle the JSON event?  Assuming all event have identical schema, do I have to provide the schema, and if so how is it done, also, if there's a way to infer the schema how is that done?

If I understand correctly I then create a *tempView*, how do I run sql-like queries on that view?

Edit required by your system: The auto system flagged this post as duplicate, it isn't.  In the linked question the OP asked to fix a problem with his existing code, and the one (valid) answer addressed issues with deserialization of JSON.
My question/s are different as stated above.  If my question wasn't clear please ask specifically and I will try to clarify further.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read records in JSON format from Kafka using Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297973/how-to-read-records-in-json-format-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming)

Comment: Thanks for adding this, however I looked at that post, and it doesn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming all event have identical schema, do I have to provide the
> schema, and if so how is it done, also, if there's a way to infer the
> schema how is that done?

Better side, if you know schema, provide a schema. You can create a schema as follows:

```
val schema = new StructType().add( "Id",IntegerType).add( "name",StringType)
```

Then read the data from Kafka and deserialize it as follows:

```
val data_df = df.select(from_json(col("value"), schema).as("data")).select("data.*")
```

You can create a temporary view out of data_df.

```
data_df.createOrReplaceTempView("data_df")
```

Now you can query the view using spark sql

```
spark.sql("select * from data_df").show()
```