# Spark-SQL reading JSON data slow

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use `Spark-SQL` to read and select data from a JSON string.

Here is what I did：

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setAppName("aaa");
sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]");

JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SparkSession sc = SparkSession.builder().sparkContext(javaSparkContext.sc()).getOrCreate();

String data = "{\"temp\":25, \"hum01\":50, \"env\":{\"lux\":1000, \"geo\":[32.5, 43.8]}}";
String querySql = "select env.lux as abc from testData";

System.out.println("start 01, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
List<String> dataList = Arrays.asList(data);
Dataset<String> dataset = sc.createDataset(dataList, Encoders.STRING());
dataset.printSchema();
System.out.println("start 02, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
Dataset<Row> df = sc.read().json(dataset);
System.out.println("start 03, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
List<String> queryResultJson = null;
try{
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("testData");
  System.out.println("start 04, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
  Dataset<Row> queryData = sc.sql(querySql);
  System.out.println("start 05, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
  queryResultJson = queryData.toJSON().collectAsList();
  System.out.println("start 06, time is"+System.currentTimeMillis());
}catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  sc.catalog().dropTempView("testData");
}
```

The result is look like this:

```
start 01, time is1543457455652
start 02, time is1543457458766
start 03, time is1543457459993
start 04, time is1543457460190
start 05, time is1543457460334
start 06, time is1543457460818
```

It seems like that the dataset creation process takes too much time. I want to use this function in a streaming data process flow. But the performance is too poor to use.

Is there any way to make dataset creation go faster?
Or is there any other method to query a Json data with SQL like language?

Comment: Using Spark structured streaming you won't create your dataset like that. You will directly read it from the stream. It's also recommended to use a predefined schema instead of relying on Spark inference.

Comment: Thank you very much! Big help. So with the streaming mode, I can send all the data to a Socket and then build a stream processing all the data received from the Socket. Is this right?  Besides, is there examples how I can use a predefined schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't create your dataset the same way when using spark structured streaming.
For example if your source is a socket with a schema describing your data:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Simple Application")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate();
StructType sensorSchema = new StructType().add("temp", new IntegerType())
        .add("hum01", new IntegerType())
        .add("env", new StructType()
                                .add("lux", new IntegerType())
                                .add("geo", new ArrayType(new FloatType(), false)));
Dataset<Row> socketDF = spark
    .readStream()
    .format("socket")
    .option("host", "localhost")
    .option("port", 9999)
    .schema()
    .load()
    .selectExp("temp, hum01, env");
```

Then you can start to benchmark your algorithm.

Comment: Hi, do I always need a schema if I want to use structed streaming to process Json data?

Comment: No you don't. It's recommended

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297973/how-to-read-records-in-json-format-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming, it is stated that there are two ways to parse Json data with structured streaming. But the first way needs a shcema, the second way only parse a few items. What I want is to parse data with Sql like language(where functions could be used) and I don't know the schema. There may be different types of Json data to process. Could this be possible?

Comment: If you have heterogeneous data in your stream it's going to be quite complex. You will need to find a way to tel in the stream what kind of data to know how you can handle it. But there is nothing built-in in spark for such usecase (in json at least). Maybe a third party lib could help you with that but i have no idea

Comment: Thanks a lot. So maybe the sample code is the only way I can use, although it is quit slow...

Comment: You may need to tweak your cluster size