# How to parse a json string column in pyspark's DataStreamReader and create a Data Frame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am reading messages from a kafka topic

```
messageDFRaw = spark.readStream\
                    .format("kafka")\
                    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
                    .option("subscribe", "test-message")\
                    .load()

messageDF = messageDFRaw.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING) as dict")
```

When I print the data frame from the above query I get the below console output.

```
|key|dict|
|#badbunny |{"channel": "#badbunny", "username": "mgat22", "message": "cool"}|
```

How can I create a data frame from the DataStreamReader such that I have a dataframe with columns as `|key|channel| username| message|`

I tried following the accepted answer in  [How to read records in JSON format from Kafka using Structured Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297973/how-to-read-records-in-json-format-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming)

```
struct = StructType([
    StructField("channel", StringType()),
    StructField("username", StringType()),
    StructField("message", StringType()),
])

messageDFRaw.select(from_json("CAST(value AS STRING)", struct))
```

but, I get `Expected type 'StructField', got 'StructType' instead` in `from_json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ignored the warning `Expected type 'StructField', got 'StructType' instead` in `from_json()`.

However, I had to cast the value from kafka message initially and then parse the json schema later.

```
messageDF = messageDFRaw.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

messageParsedDF = messageDF.select(from_json("value", struct_schema).alias("message"))

messageFlattenedDF = messageParsedDF.selectExpr("value.channel", "value.username", "value.message")
```